# Flash iPhone Packer - iAds

Tags: flash, ios

I am looking to create an application in Flash for the iPhone / iPad but I see absolutely no documentation on referencing external API's.  Most specifically, I want to access the iAds API so I can add ads to the program.  The forums have about 20 people asking with never a single reply.

Does anyone here know if it's even possible, and if not, is there any work around for getting some sort of ads into the application to earn money off it?

Comment: great question. Did you have any luck with this? I want to start looking into all this ios flash development, but resources are quite limited

Comment: At the time I asked there was no support for external API's.  I ended up going with Unity for game development and love it.

Answer (score -4):

Flash is not supported on iOS devices.

Comment: The iPhone Packager is absolutely supported on iOS devices.  The Flash Player is not currently allowed in the safari browser.

Comment: As the title said, I am specifically looking at the iPhone Packer (Packager). I would appreciate removing the down vote on my question.

Comment: For proof of my assertion that iPhone Packager is supported on iOS, see : http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/09/09statement.html